# Order type of standard models of arithmetic

Tags: logic, model-theory, ordinals

The standard model of PA has order type $\omega$. By compactness PA has a model of order type $\omega+n$ for any $n$, since every finite subset of the following set of statements is provable:

- "$\exists$ $x_1, ...,x_n$ $>1$ s.t. $x_1>...>x_n$"

  "$\exists$ $x_1, ...,x_n$ $>2$ s.t. $x_1>...>x_n$"

  $\vdots$

  "$\exists$ $x_1, ...,x_n$ $>m$ s.t. $x_1>...>x_n$"

  $\vdots$

You can get $\omega * 2$ by taking, for all $m \in \mathbb{N} $:

- "$\exists$ $x_1, ..., x_m$ $>m$ s.t. $x_1>...>x_m$.

To get $\omega * n$, take for all $m \in \mathbb{N} $:

- "$\exists$ $x^1_1,...,x^1_m, ...,x^{n-1}_1, ..., x^{n-1}_m$ $>m$ s.t.
  $x^1_1>...>x^1_m>...>x^{n-1}_1>...>x^{n-1}_m$"

Etc. This leads me to the question:

**True or false: PA has a model of order type $\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$.**

Comment: As Brian said, you cannot get $\omega+n$ as the order-type of a model of PA. There are two separate errors in your argument. First, all of the sentences $(\exists x_1,\dots,x_n>k)\,(x_1>\dots>x_n)$ are simultaneously true in the standard model, of order-type $\omega$. Second, if you correct that error by using, as is standard in compactness arguments, sentences $c_1>\dots c_n>k$ (for fixed $n$ and arbitrary $k$), where the $c$'s are new constant symbols, then compactness gives a model that *includes* a copy of $\omega+n$, but includes many more elements too.

Comment: I see why Brian is right, but I don't see the difference between my argument and the "usual" one which adds new constants. Of course for each $k$ the particular sentence $\exists x>k$ is true in the standard model, but there aren't any elements in the SM which are greater than all the usual numbers. So there must be another model where there are such elements, right?

Comment: NVM, I see. Thanks!

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37418/462).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can prove that every element except $0$ has an immediate predecessor, so you cannot get any of the order types $\omega+n$ for $n>0$ or $\omega\cdot 2$. Every model has an order type of the form $\omega+(\omega^*+\omega)\cdot\eta$ for some dense linear order type $\eta$ without endpoints;. In particular, if the model is countable, $\eta$ is the order type of the rationals.

**Added:** Each of the $\omega^*+\omega$ blocks is a $\Bbb Z$-*chain*. To see that $\eta$ must be densely ordered, suppose that $x$ and $y$ are from different $\Bbb Z$-chains. In $\mathsf{PA}$ you can define $\left\lfloor\frac{x+y}2\right\rfloor$, and it cannot be in the same $\Bbb Z$-chain as either $x$ or $y$. Similarly, if $\left\lfloor\frac{x}2\right\rfloor$ and $2x$ much be in different $\Bbb Z$-chains from $x$, so there is neither a first nor a last $\Bbb Z$-chain.